# How to use the output of a function in another function?

Tags: python, function, datetime, typeerror

I created a function to get date from the user and convert it into `datetime` format using `strptime`. The function is called `Obtaindate()`. This will go as input into another function `Getdata()`. Now, in the second function `Getdata()` I need to subtract the date from `Obtaindate()` with `timedelta`. But I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'`.

What should I do to get the date from the 1st function to work in the second function?

Here is the code sample:

```py
def ObtainDate():
   
    isValid=False

    while not isValid:

        userin = str(input("Type Date ddmmyy: "))
        
        try: 
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(userin, '%d%m%y')
            print('You have selected {}'.format(datetime.date.strftime(dt, '%d-%b-%Y')))
            break
        except:
            print("Incorrect format...try again!")
            continue

            return dt

ObtainDate()
    
def Getdata():
    
    date1 = ObtainDate() - datetime.timedelta(1)
    date2 = datetime.datetime.today()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(1)
    
    while date1 < date2:

        print('Download in progress...')
```

Comment: Did you return a value from the first function? It looks like it is returning `None`.

Comment: In the `Obtaindate` function, use `return dt` instead of `break`. As your code is written in the example, the return will never be reached since it is placed *after* `continue`. Therefore, the function returns `None` as you only break the while loop without returning something.

Comment: Beside the point, but [a bare `except` is bad practice](/q/54948548/4518341), especially on a multi-line `try`-block. Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like `except ValueError`, or at least `except Exception`, and use an `else`-block for code to run if no exception occurs.

Comment: `return dt` is indented two times more than it should be. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @wjandrea jup, an `else: return dt` would be best I think, in terms of readability.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments, I wanted to highlight some particular ones and reply directly but unable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - comments inlne to show add.mmove/delete

The except isn’t very nice - better to catch the specific exception(s)

```
def ObtainDate():
   
    isValid=False

    while not isValid:

        userin = str(input("Type Date ddmmyy: "))
        
        try: 
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(userin, '%d%m%y')
            print('You have selected {}'.format(datetime.date.strftime(dt, '%d-%b-%Y')))

            return dt    ####### moved here
        except:
            print("Incorrect format...try again!")
            continue

# REMOVED        return dt

def Getdata(adate): # ADDED PARAMETER
    
    date1 = adate- datetime.timedelta(1) # USE PARAMETER
    date2 = datetime.datetime.today()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(1)
    
    while date1 < date2:

        print('Download in progress...')
        # ADDED SAVING DATA
        data_for_this_date = …

    # ADDED RETURN
    return data_for_this_date

# ADDED SAVING VALUE OF FUNCTION CALL
theday = ObtainDate()
# ADDED PASSING the result from Obtaindate()
# AND ADDED store result returned by Getdata in a variable
data = Getdata( theday )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me out! I learned a lot from your answer.